# How do I resolve an InvalidArgumentError in Classifier model?

Tags: tensorflow

New to TensorFlow, so apologies for newbie question.

Following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough) but instead of using image data I am using numerical data.

**Load the dataset:**

```
train_dataset_url = "xxx.csv"
train_dataset_fp = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
  fname=os.path.basename(train_dataset_url),
  origin=train_dataset_url)
```

**Make training dataset:**

```
batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(
    train_dataset_fp,
    batch_size, 
    column_names=column_names,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1)
```

**Train classified model using:**

`model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
])`

But when I "test" the model with the same inputs:

`predictions = model(features)`

I receive the error:

`InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute MatMul as input #0(zero-based) was expected to be a float tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:MatMul]`

It's possible I have missed something fundamental. I feel like I need to specify a type somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The data which you feed in the model is a  numpy array according to my assumption . The error states that the model requires a tensor with dtype=float32 or float64. You are providing a int32 numpy array. So, wherever you create a numpy array, just mention the dtype as float32.

Comment: The data comes from a CSV file and I don't specify the type, although I can see it is inferred as an int32. The same data is fed back into itself when I do the test. Is there another step I could be missing?

Comment: Could you also add the code snippet in which you parse the data from the csv file?